# How to release strings in Android jni?

Tags: java, android, cordova, java-native-interface

I see alot of post concerning the Android Jni but I still do not have a clear idea how to edit it.  I have a Phonegap app that is having JNI Errors when loading a certain page.

From what I have read during research, I need to release the local storage.  How do I do this, I am wondering.

All I see to do it but no real clear path on what to do.

If you were going to either release localRef strings or create a globalRef string What would you do?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Error like [phonegap.js crashes android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459458/phonegap-js-crashes-android-app)? Have you written any Java<>JNI<>C code? What JNI error do you get?

Comment: I have written Java.  I have made a number of Phongap apps with Eclipse.  What I don't know is where to write the java to release the localRefs in the android project.

Comment: I have read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376833/referencetable-overflow-max-1024  but it still leaves me lost on were to edit or add code to release the localRefs.

Comment: You don't have to release local references in JNI, they are all released when your JNI method exits. *What* 'JNI errors' are you getting?

Comment: 05-25 11:54:34.046: E/dalvikvm(5286): Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)

Answer (score 0):

So you have already created 512 local references and you need to create more. You either have to release some of the ones you've already created, via `DeleteLocalRef()`, if that makes sense in your code, or else request more local slots, via `EnsureLocalCapacity()` or `PushLocalFrame()`. I prefer the latter in conjunction with `PopLocalFrame()`: many coding patterns fit into it, maybe yours.